# Convolve every row in a matrix with the same function

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm having difficulty convolving every row in a matrix with the same function without using a for loop. I was wondering if there's a simpler way to do this.

Comment: yes you can, but why not use a for loop, most likely it'd as fast...

Comment: Check the three-input version of [`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)

Comment: isn't this just `conv2` where the kernel is just a row vector?